# Update all table's columns with another table's columns

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table's all columns values from another table, but it doesn't work.

I get this syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM silinecek s WHERE frameworkcode IN
>   ('AR','CF','FA','IR','KT','SER','SF','SR' at line 3

This is my query

```
UPDATE marc_subfield_structure 
SET liblibrarian = s.liblibrarian, libopac = s.libopac,
    repeatable = s.repeatable, mandatory = s.mandatory,
    kohafield = s.kohafield, tab = s.tab,
    authorised_value = s.authorised_value, authtypecode = s.authtypecode,
    value_builder = s.value_builder, isurl = s.isurl, hidden = s.hidden,
    seealso = s.seealso, link = s.link, defaultvalue = s.defaultvalue,
    maxlength = s.maxlength 
FROM 
    silinecek s 
WHERE 
    frameworkcode IN ('AR','CF','FA','IR','KT','SER','SF','SR','VR')
    AND tagfield='952';
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does it run but not do what you want it to do? And how are the 2 tables related? I don't see any join condition.

Comment: Add a join between the 2 tables. Like I said it will only work when for every row in `marc_subfield_structure` that you want to update you get exactly 1 row from `silinecek`.

Comment: @Marco Allright, I wrote sql with "Join", it looks very long query because I select limit 1 and there are much columns but it works. thanks

Comment: 2 tables are same tables.. I create silinecek as "create table silinecek select * from marc_subfield_structure Where tagfield=952;

Comment: Is the `marc_subfield_structure` empty?

Comment: Doesn't it have a (primary) key? This way you might get a simpler join.

Comment: If you added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` output for the 2 tables and a few (3-4) sample rows from each and what you want to happen, it would be much better. And much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Marco it has. it is twin table

Comment: which kind of update syntax do you use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: @miracle173 There is no "from"  syntax in that link which you gave .. I saw a website and I used "from"...

Comment: that link is the "MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual". which website did you see?

Comment: @miracle173 I can't find that website which I saw. I searched and saw in google.

Comment: @AhmetMelihBaşbuğ maybe you saw a `SUBQUERY` using a `FROM` in the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL syntax for multi-table updates does not contain a `FROM` clause. Therefore MySQL raises an error message and tells you that the the error is near the `FROM` clause and that [you should check the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Your statement should be something like:

```
UPDATE 
  marc_subfield_structure m 
JOIN
  silinecek s ON m.something=s.something
SET 
    m.liblibrarian=s.liblibrarian, 
    m.libopac=s.libopac,
    m.repeatable=s.repeatable, 
    m.mandatory=s.mandatory,
    m.kohafield=s.kohafield, 
    m.tab=s.tab,
    m.authorised_value=s.authorised_value, 
    m.authtypecode=s.authtypecode,
    m.value_builder=s.value_builder, 
    m.isurl=s.isurl, 
    m.hidden=s.hidden,
    m.seealso=s.seealso, 
    m.link=s.link,
    m.defaultvalue=s.defaultvalue,
    m.maxlength=s.maxlength 
WHERE s.frameworkcode IN ('AR','CF','FA','IR','KT','SER','SF','SR','VR')
AND s.tagfield='952';
```

But I don't know either the structure of your tables or the purpose of your query, so that is just to give you the idea about the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You (can) get multiple rows from `silinecek`. This is not correct you must make sure that you get one and only one row. This you get by adding a join between the 2 tables.